# Ways to filter specific value of array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I haven't use numpy to his full potential yet. I have this pretty huge 3d array (700000 x 32 x 32). All of the values are int between 1 and 4. I want to be able to filter the array so that the I get a same shape array, but only with 1 for values of 4 and 0 for everything else.

For example,

```
[[4, 2, 2, 3],      [[1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 4, 4, 2],       [0, 1, 1, 0],
 [2, 4, 1, 3],   ->  [0, 1, 0, 0],
 [2, 3, 2, 4]]       [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

It works with `np.where(array==4)`. I get a huge 3d array that I can reshape, but would there more *numpy* way to do it ? Thanks.

Comment: Just `(array==4).astype(int)`?

Comment: Yes simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr = np.array([[4, 2, 2, 3],      
                [1, 4, 4, 2],       
                [2, 4, 1, 3],  
                [2, 3, 2, 4]])

In[58]: (arr==4).astype(int)

Out[58]: array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 1, 0],
                [0, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get it with **np.where** without having to reshape it with the next expression:

```
arr = np.array([[4, 2, 2, 3],      
                [1, 4, 4, 2],       
                [2, 4, 1, 3],  
                [2, 3, 2, 4]])

np.where(arr == 4, 1, 0)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: This is also good and fast, but the accepted answer is like 5% faster

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.zeros((5,5))
matrix[0]=[1,-2,3,4,-5]
matrix[2]=[0,1,4,0,4]
matrix=np.array([[1 if value==4 else 0 for value in row ] for row in matrix])
```

[image]

The above snippet uses nested list comprehension & than converts  list back to np array

Comment: Yes this gets the job done well for a 2d or 3d matrix, but the use of for loops take a long time to compute. My array is pretty big. The other answer is better in my case.